# Problem with navigating to LWCs wrapped in aura component

Tags: lightning-web-components, aura, navigation, navigationmixin.navigate

I have a requirement where I need to navigate to LWCs. I referred [this](https://salesforcediaries.com/2020/06/07/navigate-to-lightning-web-component-from-another-lightning-web-component/) website and used aura component for the navigation. I do not wish to use tabs, hence I chose this option. There are 4 LWCs and each LWC navigates to the next LWC (LWC 1 -> LWC 2 -> LWC 3 -> LWC 4). I do not wish to use multiple aura components hence I implemented it using a single aura component.

The problem is that the navigation works for the 1st time and after that, every navigation needs a manual refresh. I think the problem occurs due to caching. There is a change in URL but the new LWC does not load until the page is manually refreshed. I am trying to find a way to solve the issue without disabling caching for LWCs.

**Code used for navigation to the next LWC:**

```js
//This code is used for navigation to the next LWC. It is executed when next button is clicked on the LWC.
handleNextButton(){
  this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
    type: "standard__component",
    attributes: {
      componentName: "c__NavigateToLWC" //This is the name of the aura component
    },
    state: {
      c__nameOfLWC: 'customReportFilterLWC' //This is the name of the LWC to which we want to navigate
    }
  });
}
```

***Note:*** *Above code is the same for all LWCs except the `state:` part of it.*

**Aura Component Code:**

```html
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,lightning:isUrlAddressable" access="global">
    
    <!-- Create flags and set the default value to false. -->
    <aura:attribute name="customReportFilterLWCFlag" type="boolean" default="false"/>
    <aura:attribute name="customReportSortingLWCFlag" type="boolean" default="false"/>
    <aura:attribute name="customReportPreviewLWCFlag" type="boolean" default="false"/>
    
    <!-- Call the init handler. It will set a flag to true -->
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}"/>   
    
    <!-- Display the LWC that has the corresponding flag set to true in the init handler -->
    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.customReportFilterLWCFlag}">
        <c:customReportFilterLWC/>
    </aura:if>
    
    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.customReportSortingLWCFlag}">
        <c:customReportSortingLWC/>
    </aura:if>
    
    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.customReportPreviewLWCFlag}">
        <c:customReportPreviewLWC/>
    </aura:if>
    
</aura:component>
```

**Aura Controller Code:**

```js
({
    init: function(component, event, helper) {
        
        //Get the name of the LWC to which we need to navigate
        var pageRef = component.get("v.pageReference");
        var navigateToLWC = pageRef.state.c__nameOfLWC;
        
        //Check the name of the LWC and set the corresponding flag to true
        if(navigateToLWC == 'customReportFilterLWC'){
            
            component.set("v.customReportFilterLWCFlag", "true");
            
        }else if(navigateToLWC == 'customReportSortingLWC'){
            
            component.set("v.customReportSortingLWCFlag", "true");
            
        }else if(navigateToLWC == 'customReportPreviewLWC'){
            
            component.set("v.customReportPreviewLWCFlag", "true");
            
        }
        
        //Refresh the page to open the next LWC.
        //$A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();
        
    }
})
```

I thought that forcing a refresh would solve the issue but it does not. The browser hangs and does not load. I get the following error message:

[image]

I am not able to find a way out. Please guide. Thank You!

Comment: Have a look on [DIRECTLY NAVIGATE TO LIGHTNING WEB COMPONENT WITHOUT USING AURA COMPONENT](https://salesforcediaries.com/2020/06/08/directly-navigate-to-lightning-web-component-without-using-aura-component/) .

Comment: @sanketkumar Thanks for the response! I had taken a look at it before. It's using URL for navigation and isn't a long term solution.

Comment: For your current approach, how are you handling the navigation from LWC2 to LWC3? Can you post the code snippet for LWC2 or LWC3? I suspect you should dispatch a custom event from these child LWC to aura component and handle it accordingly. You current code snippet doesn't show any of this? Note that aura _init_ event executes only once for component initialization. Also, why do you say @sanketkumar's recommendation isn't a long term solution? Can you elaborate your use case?

Comment: @arut Thank you for the response! I used `NavigationMixin.Navigate` for navigation when the user presses the `Next` button on the LWC. Please see the first code snippet in the question. I have added comments to it for better understanding. As for @sanketkumar's recommendation, it will work only as long as the URL stays the same. Any change in the URL portion `'/one/one.app#'` in the future will fail the navigation. Hence I said that it's not a long-term solution.

Comment: I wouldn't be worried about any change to `/one/one.app#` in the near future, but would agree to a probable deprecation to the the old way of base64 encoded info about the component details in the URL. But, this may not happen anytime soon IMO. Also, using the [page reference types](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_page_reference_type) available in LWC, I guess there should be a different approach, but depends on your requirements. Check if the posted answer would solve the problem in your current approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lightning:isUrlAddressable` is an Aura interface and this [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:isUrlAddressable/documentation) states the following:

> The lightning:isUrlAddressable interface extends the
> lightning:hasPageReference interface. A component that implements
> lightning:isUrlAddressable then gets access to the page state through
> the pageReference attribute. The page state is a representation of the
> current URL query parameters.
>
> lightning:isUrlAddressable enables you to generate a user-friendly URL
> for a Lightning component with the pattern /cmp/componentName
>
> Important: When the target of a navigation action maps to the same
> component, the routing container might simply update the pageReference
> attribute value instead of recreating the component. In this scenario,
> a change handler ensures that your component reacts correctly.

***Note the last point about the update to the `pageReference` attribute value and the need to have a change handler***. Your aura component has the init method which will execute only once for the component initialization. But, there is no handler method corresponding to any change in the `pageReference` attribute value. So, when the NEXT button handler executes, the `pageReference` value is updated but no handler is present to update the boolean attributes.

In the following code snippet, you have mentioned that the `attributes` value will remain same in all LWCs, but the `state` value will change.

```
this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
    type: "standard__component",
    attributes: {
      componentName: "c__NavigateToLWC" //This is the name of the aura component
    },
    state: {
      c__nameOfLWC: 'customReportFilterLWC' //This is the name of the LWC to which we want to navigate
    }
  });
```

So, your aura component HTML should include the following code. This will invoke the `init` method every time there is a change to `pageReference`. *Note that if you have additional code in the `init` method that should not be executed everytime, then create a separate JS method as the change handler*.

```
<aura:handler name="change" value="{!v.pageReference}" action="{!c.init}"/>
```

And, the init method in the aura controller JS should be as follows:

```
init: function(component, event, helper) {
        
    //Get the name of the LWC to which we need to navigate
    var pageRef = component.get("v.pageReference");
    var navigateToLWC = pageRef.state.c__nameOfLWC;
    
    //Check the name of the LWC and set the corresponding flag to true
    if(navigateToLWC == 'customReportFilterLWC'){
    
        component.set("v.customReportSortingLWCFlag", "false");
        component.set("v.customReportPreviewLWCFlag", "false");
        component.set("v.customReportFilterLWCFlag", "true");
        
    }else if(navigateToLWC == 'customReportSortingLWC'){
        
        component.set("v.customReportPreviewLWCFlag", "false");
        component.set("v.customReportFilterLWCFlag", "false");
        component.set("v.customReportSortingLWCFlag", "true");
        
    }else if(navigateToLWC == 'customReportPreviewLWC'){
        
        component.set("v.customReportSortingLWCFlag", "false");
        component.set("v.customReportFilterLWCFlag", "false");
        component.set("v.customReportPreviewLWCFlag", "true");
        
    }   
}
```

---

Alternate approach:

If you are embedding all the LWCs inside an aura component, I don't see a need for `NavigationMixin.Navigate` in all 4 components. Instead, you can do the following:

- Dispatch a custom event from the LWC and this custom event should include (in its `detail` attribute) the name corresponding to the boolean attribute.
- Handle the custom event on the parent Aura component by obtaining the `detail` attribute value to update the boolean attributes, thereby controlling which LWC is displayed.

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot for the detailed answer. The alternate approach suggested by you will use `events` in all 4 LWCs instead of `NavigationMixin.Navigate`. The aura component will be needed regardless. But is there any performance advantage in using `events` instead of `NavigationMixin.Navigate`?

Comment: I also looked at alternate approaches which will eliminate the use of aura component for navigation. **Approach 1:** Use parent LWC and embed child LWCs inside it -[Link](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/300837/evaluation-of-approach-to-navigate-between-3-lwc-pages). **Approach 2:** Use Flows to navigate between LWCs -[Link](https://www.jitendrazaa.com/blog/salesforce/point-and-click/use-lightning-web-components-in-flow/). Please provide short feedback on these approaches. Thanks again!

Comment: I don't see any performance advantage of using `events` over `NavigationMixin.Navigate`. While `NavigationMixin` will still work for your case, its primarily built to navigate to different pages (based on page type & by manipulating the `PageReference` JS object). I don't see a point in using this if the user is going to be staying on the same page for all the LWCs (_unless there is valid use case not mentioned in your question_). In fact, **Approach 1** mentioned in your comment is well suited for your use case IMO, thereby eliminating Aura comp & building everything on LWC.

Comment: **Approach 1** vs **Approach 2** is just a matter of preference based on the business requirements. Your use case can be implemented in either of these. If you use **Approach 2**, you would use screen elements that is best suited for user guidance scenario and comes with a _previous_, _next_ & _finish_ buttons. You would also have flow variables which can be used to capture the input & output data between various components. In **Approach 1**, you would do the same using _custom events_ to send data from child components to parent & _public methods_ to call child comp methods from parent.